# Compiling Git on redhat with libcurl using openssl and not GnuTLS

Tags: git, redhat

We want to compile Git on Redhat Linux 8 such that it uses libcurl with
openssl and not GnuTLS.

```
yum install -y gcc \
        make \
        autoconf \
        gettext \
        curl-devel \
        openssl-devel \
        perl-devel \
        zlib-devel 

gitVersion=2.35.1
url="https://github.com/git/git/archive/refs/tags/v$gitVersion.tar.gz"

tempDir=$(mktemp -d) &&
        mkdir -p "$tempDir" &&
        (
            cd "$tempDir" &&
                curl -L "$url" -o git.tar.gz &&
                tar -xf git.tar.gz &&
                cd "$tempDir/git-"* &&
                make configure &&
                ./configure --prefix="$installDir" \
                    --with-curl \
                    --with-expat \
                    --with-openssl \
                    --without-python \
                    --without-tcltk \
                    --sysconfdir=/etc \
                    --with-gitconfig=/etc/gitconfig &&
                make -j all &&
                sudo make -j install
```

I am however not really sure now if Git is really using openssl, how can I inspect `libcurl.so` from the system to see if it uses `openssl` or `gnuttls` ? Do I need to compile my own libcurl?
Does `ldd` output helps here?

Comment: For me, the approach described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/438734 worked fine!